# Show the progress of committing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, svn, commit

I need to show a process of committing my files to the SVN. I use vs2008 C#. I take a progress bar, but when I am starting committing, I don't know how to show my progress (also I want to look what file is uploading now in a label for example)

Comment: why do you need that? you have TortoiseSVN

Comment: I create an util, that use api osubversion

Comment: Maybe you should instead use the API from [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/)

Comment: sorry, forgot to tell, that I'm using it ))!

Comment: This isn't easy to implement, especially for Subversion 1.6. I would recommend just copying the code I wrote for that purpose in AnkhSVN. This code is part of the Progress dialog and the source is available in:
http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/svn/ankhsvn/trunk/src/Ankh.UI/ProgressDialog.cs (username guest, no password. Or your open collabnet login credentials)

Comment: @BertHuijben - Link rot. That page says that the item is not found. :(

Comment: https://ctf.open.collab.net/svn/repos/ankhsvn/trunk/src/Ankh.UI/ProgressDialog.cs should work